# How To Show That B is Semi-Decidable Given A

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem, semi-decidability

I am preparing for my Computational Theory final and ran into this exact problem :

*B={ x | there exists a prefix of x that is in A}.*

Show that ***B*** is semi-decidable.  In other words, you need to describe an algorithm ***M*** that on input a string ***x*** semi-decides if some prefix of ***x*** is in ***A*** (“semi-decides” means that it is OK if the algorithm loops for strings with no prefix in ***A***). You will assume that you have an algorithm ***M<sub>A</sub>*** that semi-decides ***A***.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A language is semi-decidable if there is a Turing machine that halts for all strings in the language, and doesn't halt for strings not in the language.

You are given that $A$ is semi-decidable. Therefore there is a Turing machine $M$ that halts on an input $x$ iff $x \in A$. Your goal is to construct another Turing machine $M'$ that halts on an input $x$ iff one of the prefixes of $x$ is in $A$. In other words, $M'$ should halt on $x$ iff $M$ halts on one of the prefixes of $x$.

You take it from here.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help. Ive constructed a Turing machine **_M'_**. If **_M'_** halts on the prefix of **_x_** and the prefix of **_x_** is not in **_A_**, then **_M'_** rejects.  If **_M'_** halts on the prefix of **_x_** and the prefix of **_x_** IS in **_A_**, then simulate: **_M_** on **_x_**. 1) accept if **_M_** accepts **_x_** 2) reject if **_M_** rejects **_x_**. 3) else loop forever. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: An input has several prefixes. How do you handle that?